# Return value of updateEmail() - firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I want to check if updateEmail() goes through or not. If it changes an email or not and I don't know what is the return value of that function so I can check it.

I tried something like this

```
if(user.updateEmail(email) != null) {
  msg = "Success";
}
```

And I am never getting a null value if it is good or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return values of the [`User.updateEmail` method](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/User/updateEmail.html) is `Future<void>`. So while the future has no resulting value, you can check whether it succeeded or failed by [checking the result of the future itself](https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/futures-error-handling). From there, it looks like it should be something like this:

```
user.updateEmail(email).then(() {
  msg = "Success";
})
.catchError(handleError);
```

Comment: It looks good, but got "Undefined name 'handleError'."

Comment: That is where you would handle your error. Print to console, create a dialog box with the error, etc